# Trigger exe in EC2 to process new file uploaded to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a service running in EC2 instance. The server contains an exe which takes file name as a parameter and do some logic. I.E. whenever a file is uploaded to S3, it will trigger the exe to process the file.

Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

what i have done is, i have created a SQS, and open the notification on S3 bucket to that sqs. when a file is uploaded i get a notification in sqs. i wrote an application which reads the sqs and extract name from its values and call the application with that name as parameters.

Comment: Is it possible doing with lambda function? If yes any clue?

Comment: https://cloudonaut.io/integrate-sqs-and-lambda-serverless-architecture-for-asynchronous-workloads/

Comment: I have certain parameters to pass. How can i pass it to the exe which is in EC2 from S3?

Comment: Any suggestions on this.